# Анти-спам... защита от ботов

Tags: php, безопасность

Всем привет. Подскажите, как можно реализовать при регистрации вывод 4-х значных цифр при регистрации, так же проверку этих цифр... типа если пользователь ввел неправильно цифры, то регистрация не пройдет. Я не прошу написать код, я прошу только саму идею, как это осуществить) Я начинающий, так что помогите, буду благодарен)

Comment: Только не делайте плиз капчу как у гугла `>_<` У меня такой ярости даже синий экран не вызывает))

Comment: Капчи вообще не должно быть видно, если нет реальной необходимости. Вместо нее можно использовать proof-of-work системы a-la [Hashcash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcash), которую типичный спам-бот уже не потянет. Открыл пользователь страницу, заполняет форму — webworker в фоне дробит числа, ищет коллизии хэшей. А капчу включать только если не посчитал (отключен JavaScript или браузер древний) или стали наглеть. Хотя, опять же, от наглеющих капча никак не спасет — их решают, грубо говоря, по доллару за тыщу капч.

Comment: Это я в смысле, что лучше, перед тем как ставить капчу («потому что у всех так») подумать, а нужна и эффективна ли она. От типично тупых спам-ботов — проверено! — защитит переименование настоящих полей в «мусорные» названия (скажем, «s5fSWb8i» вместо «email») и нагло названное в духе «username» банальное скрытое поле (которое бот сдуру заполнит, а человек даже не увидит). И не будет [театра безопасности](http://www.computerra.ru/focus/295368/) в виде неудобной капчи.

Comment: да нет, я не собираюсь делать уж супер глобальную систему от ботов) всего то и надо чтобы выводилось 3-4 цифры для подтверждения регистрации) не думаю что на мой ученический первый проект в виде чата станут атаки роботов делать ) спасибо всем

Answer (score 5):

Идея основана на том что [бот не может распознать то, что может распознать человек](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA).

Проект KCAPTCHA — это готовое решение, написанное на языке PHP, которое вы можете бесплатно скачать и установить на свой сайт для защиты от спама и флуда.
http://captcha.ru/kcaptcha/

В архиве с библиотекой есть пример как с ней работать.

Answer (score 3):

Вот на сто процентов правильно сказал **Vfvtnjd** в первом предложении. Всё гениальное просто. Вы же не от хакеров защиту ставите, а от ботов, которые работают по определенным алгоритмам. Я вам приведу пример, который без всяких картинок-каптчей работает на трех сайтах моих клиентов и на все 100%.
В поле предлагается ввести решение простейшего примера, который описан комбинировано, например:

*"2 + I0 и умножить на два = "*

За два года ни один бот не пробил. Числа "два" и "I0" - постоянные, первое число формируется текущей датой date('d'); Проверку в файле обработчике сделать элементарно. К тому же число десять написано как буква "I" и цифра "0".

Comment: Deonis, а можно по подробней пожалуйста? ) интересно!

Answer (score 2):

Можно пользоваться [готовыми скриптами](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=246), не теряя времени, но изучать-настраивать та придется все таки.

Можно например, поставить "хуки", на нажатие клавиш: смотрим, что нажал пользователь, смотрим код клавиш, и проверяем на условие,и т д. 
Взгляньте например, для начала на эти
ресурсы.

[Проверка поля. Вводим только цифры](http://itseazy.ru/post95)

[Фильтрация и проверка данных полей](http://mpbox.ru/collect/js-plugins/forms/filtering-and-data-validation-fields.html)

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но я сам бы хотел потратить свое время и написать своими руками) в интернете много готовых скриптов, но приятней же когда сам пишешь, а по итого оно еще и работает) за ссылки спасибо вам обоим, почитаю)

Comment: последняя ссылка умерла. вот теперь где она - [Фильтрация и проверка данных полей][1]


  [1]: http://mpbox.ru/collect/js-plugins/forms/filtering-and-data-validation-fields.html

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, будет полезно [это](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120851/).

Есть мнение (см. там же, альтернативы capcha), что от капчи "нужно" отказаться.